# Slide up animation in Android is not smooth

Tags: android, listview

Slide up animation in Android is not smooth in some devices with Android version 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 while it runs perfectly in the others

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: What's your question? If the code is literally the same on each phone then the CPU is probably just too slow to handle the animation.

Comment: android:repeatCount="infinite" set this

Comment: I need the animation one time only.

Comment: The testing device is Asus Zenfone 5 so there should not be a problem of processor.